# Firebase PhoneAuthCredential expires when anonymousUser.linkWithCredential() fails

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my android app flow, the user is anonymously signed-in as soon as the app launches. The user is eventually asked to sign-in using phone number and OTP. This is done using `PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber()`. Further down the authentication flow, once the `PhoneAuthCredential` is available, I am doing the following:

```
try {
    // If already signed in anonymously, link to that account

    auth.currentUser?.linkWithCredential(credential)?.await()

} catch (e: FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException) {
    // The signed-in account already exists. Hence, it cannot be merged
    // with the anonymous account. Abandon anonymous account and sign-in 
    // with existing account.

    auth.signInWithCredential(credential).await()
}
```

This works perfectly fine for a new user. However, for an existing user who is signing-in again (reinstall/second device/etc.) this code fails. The `PhoneAuthCredential` seems to expire when passed to `linkWithCredential()`. So the subsequent call to  `auth.signInWithCredential()` throws an exception with the message:

> The SMS code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try again.

This is discussed in detail in this [Firebase Github Issue](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/6006) but without any solution or workaround.

Beacuse of this expiring credential, I am forced to just call `auth.signInWithCredential(credential)` without ever attempting `linkWithCredential()`, thereby abandoning the anonymous account even when its a new user. Is there a solution/workaround that does not require the anonymous account to be abandoned at least when a **new sign-in** happens.